# Python - Import module which has a different name to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, module

Essentially, I have two `.py` files which lie in the same directory. Namely, `foo_v02` and `bar_v01`.

In `bar_v01`, I want to import a class from `foo_v02`. However, for the sake of convenience, I want to use the statement `from foo import myClass` (ignoring the version number). However, as my file isn't called `foo`, of course `python` throws an error as there's no file called `foo.py`.

**My Question: Is there a way I can just use `from foo import myClass` without having to rename my `foo_v02.py` file?**

Note: I already have code which works but it uses `from foo_v02 import myClass`, so I'm not experiencing a problem as such. Also, I'm asking this question as my `foo_xx.py` file will undergo frequent editing so there will be multiple versions (so I don't want to have to edit the `import` statement with every new version). Also, there's only ever going to be one `foo_xx.py` in the directory as all the previous versions are moved to a different directory once they're outdated.

EDIT:

I've posted an answer for now, but if anyone has a better way, please feel free to post it!

Comment: Have you considered using version control software (like `git`) instead of filename versioning? Among other advantages, it gives a much better history of changes. Then you could name the module `foo.py` and still have a way to access all the different versions.

Comment: @unutbu Not yet, no. I have an account on `github` but I don't use it much and tbh, this isn't like some massive project with a development team. Really, I'm just looking for a quick fix if there is one.

Comment: Keep previous versions in a different directory, the current one always named `foo.py`

Comment: The _only_ correct solution to this problem is to get rid of the version number and name your file `foo.py`. Everything else is an ugly hacky workaround and not a real solution.

Comment: @Aran-Fey A workaround *is* what I'm looking for :-) See my answer below.

Comment: @wwii That involves renaming files ... please see my answer below.

Comment: Is there anyone who is interested in telling him that `git` is totally different from `github` and can be used offline and is beneficial to even a tiny project? Forgive me to use double `and` in one sentence.

Comment: @Sraw Thanks for the explanation! The main problem I have with that is just that I don't want to use a new module and I just want a quick and easy solution (which requires minimal effort)

Comment: @Adi219 git doesn't require a new module. Most programmers will use it even for one-file projects, as it means you don't need to do dumb import hacks and you don't lose your code if your computer breaks.

Comment: You should definitely take the time to learn real version control with git. Future you will be glad you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below code maybe works:

```
import glob

foo = __import__(glob.glob('foo_*.py')[0][:-3])
myClass = foo.myClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original answer got deleted...

```
import glob
a = glob.glob('*.py') ## Returns all of the `python` files
b =  a[0]
exec('from {} import myClass'.format(b[:-3]))
```

I'm using `exec()` (instead of `__import__`) as I actually want to run the `import` statement. Also, the `import` isn't discarded afterwards.